# Java restore JFrame from tray

Tags: java, swing

I have an applicaton that implements a listener for smartcards reader.

When I run the application I send it to tray.

When the aplication detects a card I want it to restore the jFrame back to normal so the user can select the options available on the screen.

Problem is when I try to restore the window it creates a new one.
How is  possible to restore the jFrame back to normal.

This code is what I have inside the jFrame constructor:
It creates the tray Icon and the options Close and Open. But I want it to open automatically. Is it possible to programatically click the Open option?

```
    initComponents();
    setResizable(false);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setTitle("App Title");
    UFRInstance = (uFrFunctions) Native.loadLibrary(GetLibFullPath(false), uFrFunctions.class);
    this.wsc = new WebSocketConnection();

    System.out.println("creating instance");
    try {
        System.out.println("setting look and feel");
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Unable to set LookAndFeel");
    }
    if (SystemTray.isSupported()) {
        System.out.println("system tray supported");
        tray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();

        Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("bulb.png");
        ActionListener exitListener = new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Exiting....");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        };
        PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu();
        MenuItem defaultItem = new MenuItem("Close");
        defaultItem.addActionListener(exitListener);
        popup.add(defaultItem);
        defaultItem = new MenuItem("Open");
        defaultItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                setVisible(true);
                setExtendedState(JFrame.NORMAL);
            }
        });
        popup.add(defaultItem);
        trayIcon = new TrayIcon(createIcon("bulb.png", "Icon"), "SystemTray Demo", popup);
        trayIcon.setImageAutoSize(true);
    } else {
        System.out.println("system tray not supported");
    }
    addWindowStateListener(new WindowStateListener() {
        public void windowStateChanged(WindowEvent e) {
            if (e.getNewState() == ICONIFIED) {
                try {
                    tray.add(trayIcon);
                    setVisible(false);
                    System.out.println("added to SystemTray");
                } catch (AWTException ex) {
                    System.out.println("unable to add to tray");
                }
            }
            if (e.getNewState() == 7) {
                try {
                    tray.add(trayIcon);
                    setVisible(false);
                    System.out.println("added to SystemTray");
                } catch (AWTException ex) {
                    System.out.println("unable to add to system tray");
                }
            }
            if (e.getNewState() == MAXIMIZED_BOTH) {
                tray.remove(trayIcon);
                setVisible(true);
                System.out.println("Tray icon removed");
            }
            if (e.getNewState() == NORMAL) {
                tray.remove(trayIcon);
                setVisible(true);
                System.out.println("Tray icon removed1");
            }
        }
    });
    setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("bulb.png"));
    setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(getClass().getResource("bulb.png")));
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

Answer (score 0):

You code contains the "Open" option, adding an ActionListener:

```
    defaultItem = new MenuItem("Open");
    defaultItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        setVisible(true);
        setExtendedState(JFrame.NORMAL);
    }
```

So all you need to do is call `setVisible(true);` and maybe the second line as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do visible. Like Below example :

```
int state = getExtendedState();
state = state & ~Frame.ICONIFIED;
setExtendedState(state);
setVisible(true);
```

The first line retrieves the current state, which is a bitmask. It then sets the ICONIFIED (minimized) part to false, then sets the same state again. This way, if the program was maximized before it will be maximimized again, etc. Of course a setVisible(true) must follow to show the window again.